# Nested MySQL Not working from Access VBA

Tags: mysql, vba

I'm trying to update my queries to MySQL and have found that I need to use nested queries to get the results I need.

I have the following code:-

```
SELECT tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, (SELECT Sum(tbl_invoices_payments.payment_amount) AS SumOfpayment_amount FROM tbl_invoices_payments WHERE invoice_id = id GROUP BY tbl_invoices_payments.invoice_id ) AS Payments
FROM tbl_invoices
WHERE (((tbl_invoices.customer_id)=11));
```

I get the error:-

## 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

The results I need are simply the SUM of all the payments for each invoice.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, Sum(tbl_invoices_payments.payment_amount) AS SumOfpayment_amount 
FROM tbl_invoices left outer join tbl_invoices_payments on tbl_invoices_payments.invoice_id = tbl_invoices.ID
GROUP BY tbl_invoices.ID
having tbl_invoices.customer_id=11;
```

Comment: Thank you Gouda, I was clearly over complicating things.

Comment: Doh!
It was looking promising, but it is not returning invoices that don't have any payments in the tbl_invoices_payments table.
Can the query include those as well?

Comment: I copied and pasted your query and the invoices without any payments are missing from the result.

Comment: change group by to be tbl_invoices.ID

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction and I ended up with this

SELECT tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, tbl_invoices.invoice_date, tbl_invoices.invoice_net, tbl_invoices.invoice_tax, tbl_invoices.invoice_gross, Sum(tbl_invoices_payments.payment_amount) AS SumOfpayment_amount
FROM tbl_invoices LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices_payments ON tbl_invoices.ID = tbl_invoices_payments.invoice_id
GROUP BY tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, tbl_invoices.invoice_date, tbl_invoices.invoice_net, tbl_invoices.invoice_tax, tbl_invoices.invoice_gross
HAVING (((tbl_invoices.customer_id)=11));

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out with the help of Gouda.

```
SELECT tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, tbl_invoices.invoice_date, tbl_invoices.invoice_net, tbl_invoices.invoice_tax, tbl_invoices.invoice_gross, Sum(tbl_invoices_payments.payment_amount) AS SumOfpayment_amount
FROM tbl_invoices LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices_payments ON tbl_invoices.ID = tbl_invoices_payments.invoice_id
GROUP BY tbl_invoices.ID, tbl_invoices.customer_id, tbl_invoices.invoice_date, tbl_invoices.invoice_net, tbl_invoices.invoice_tax, tbl_invoices.invoice_gross
HAVING (((tbl_invoices.customer_id)=11));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Consider marking Gouda's answer as accepted (the checkmark icon next to the vote buttons) instead of posting your own answer. Posting your own answer like this, despite the attribution and "thank you" note, can be considered rude, which I'm sure you didn't mean to be. "Thank you" on Stack Exchange sites is always best expressed as an upvote and/or checkmark.